# Spring cloud config server -Set directory of folder where git repo are cloned

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud

The default configuration for a Spring cloud config server is:

```
/tmp/...
```

Is there a way to change this configuration?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It actually uses the java temp dir facility, which on your system, happens to be `/tmp`.

You can set the following property to whatever directory you prefer.

`--spring.cloud.config.server.git.basedir=/var/cfgserv`

Comment: Thanks I use yml on the config using the same var to define the basedir.

Comment: thank you Spencer Gibb, your post saved me a lot. link https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-config/commit/a424690962b050bf20e9e1d6239571854c894108