# How to stop Spring Cloud Config Cloning a new version of a Repo every time the Config Server is started

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-config

Upon running a Spring Cloud Config application with a Git backend a clone is performed into the default location of `c:/user/AppData/Temp/local/<config-repo-1>`. Cloning can take a long time for larger applications (currently one of my teams takes ~15 min).
When the Config Server is stopped and restarted again instead of using the same local repo another clone is performed, `c:/user/AppData/Temp/local/<config-repo-2>`.

Is there a way to change this behavior so that restarting the Config Server does not do a new clone but instead just does a fetch for the existing clone.

Thanks in advance for any assistance provided.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring cloud config server -Set directory of folder where git repo are cloned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32317112/spring-cloud-config-server-set-directory-of-folder-where-git-repo-are-cloned)

Comment: unfortunately not.  This just changes the directory where repos are cloned but does not change the behavior of cloning a new version of the same repo each time the server is started

Answer (score 0):

```yaml
spring:
    config:
      server:
        git:
          clone-on-start: false
```

I saw this option somewhere, but couldn't figure out where I got it. Unfortunately, the official spring documentation does not refer to this option. This will not clone the rep when starting.

The other Option from the [Spring Documentation](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/reference/html/#_force_pull_in_git_repositories) is:

```yaml
spring:
    config:
      server:
        git:
          force-pull: false
```

As documented:

> ... there is a force-pull property that makes Spring Cloud Config Server force pull from the remote repository if the local copy is dirty

Comment: clone-on-start simply dictates if the repo will be cloned one the application is started or if it will wait until it has received a request for that repo and only then clone. 
force-pull looks like a property that deals with repos already cloned and not related to the start up of the application.